# add android or similar in dualboot on meizu mx4 edition ubuntu

Tags: dual-boot, ubuntu-touch, android, meizu-mx4

I want install Android and Ubuntu Touch, in dual-boot, on my Meizu. However, I fail to install both at the same time. How can I make make my device dual-boot with both Android and Ubuntu Touch?